# Converting list of pandas dataframes and series to numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert my training and test features and targets to numpy arrays. I though to be smart about it and save myself a line of code by trying:

```
for i in [train_features, train_target, test_features, test_target]:
    i = np.array(i)
```

However, this only converts the dataframe objects (features) to np arrays, not the targets, which are pandas series.

Changing the code to this had no effect:

```
converts = [train_features, train_target, test_features, test_target]
for i in range(len(converts)):
    converts[i] = np.array(i)
```

I thought it had something to do with i not referring directly to the variables, but apparently it does since it only converts the dataframes. I know I could just do this manually in 4 lines of code, but now I'm curious: why does my approach not work? And how does i refer to objects when called like this? Does it return a copy of the variable or a link to the variable it refers to?

Comment: try `i.to_numpy()`

Comment: The first makes a new array from the frame (or series), but doesn't 'store' or save that anywhere.  That's basic python iteration behavior.  In the second, `i` is a number, so `np.array(i)` is `np.array(0)` etc.  `converts[i]=` assigns that to `converts` list, but doesn't change the frames.  Again a basic python iteration issue.  You may want to practice with some simpler python loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to show what's happening with simple string variables.  We don't need dataframes and series to understand python basics.

```
In [15]: a, b, c = 'a1','b2','c3'; alist = [a,b,c]; alist
Out[15]: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

Your first iteration, changes the iteration variable, `i`, but doesn't nothing with the change:

```
In [16]: for i in alist:
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     i = i + 'more'
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     
a1
a1more
b2
b2more
c3
c3more

In [17]: alist
Out[17]: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

The list hasn't changed.  `i` is a reference to an item in the list.  `i=...` assigns a new values to that variable, but does not change the list, nor the item in the list.

Your second iteration assigns a new object to the slot in the list, but does  not change the thing that was originally assigned there:

```
In [18]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     alist[i] = 'xxx'
    ...:     

In [19]: alist
Out[19]: ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']
```

We can make a new list with modified items:

```
In [21]: alist = [a,b,c];    
In [22]: [i+'more' for i in alist]
Out[22]: ['a1more', 'b2more', 'c3more']
```

This list comprehension is a short hand for a loop that does `newlist.append(newvalue)` each time.

But that doesn't change the original list, or any of the referenced variables:

```
In [23]: alist
Out[23]: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']    
In [24]: a
Out[24]: 'a1'
```

The only way you can change `a` is to change it directly.  Lists won't help you:

```
In [25]: a=a+'more'    
In [26]: a
Out[26]: 'a1more'
```